# Multiple string grep must output the filename:target string:count in linux

Tags: shell

I wanted to grep for strings "Manager" and "DBA" in all file at current directory and provide the output as

filename:Target string:count

Comment: It doesn't really look like you've made much effort to solve this problem - have you tried anything yourself? If so, please edit your question to show us. Some sample input and the corresponding output is always helpful too.

Comment: I am aware that grep -c and grep -o will give the output but the challenge is to put them in the required format. I tried a lot. I am currently trying to get this done with awk. I am done to use grep command.

Comment: As I said, you should [edit] your question to show your attempts, explaining what you're stuck with and showing us a test case.

Comment: I tried to use two options c & o together but not resulting in expected output. I believe we will have to go for some alternative, I tried but no luck. Can you suggest some idea? 

$ grep -co "Manager\|DBA" *
@:0
300}:0
500:0
600:0
All.ear:0
All.jar:0
All.tar:8
dir:0
dir4:0
dir400:0
even:4
F1:0
F2:0
file:5
file1:0
grep: file1.txt: No such file or directory
file2.txt:0
grep: file3.txt: No such file or directory
file.tar:0
file.zip:0
Jar_Dir:0
test.sh:0

Comment: Click the [edit] link and add the additional details to your question. Don't use the comments.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you were after a one-liner or not but I think this should provide the output you would like.

Starting with two files:
test_file.txt:

```
HEre is some random text
Manager
Some stuff
Manager
Testing
This Manager did DBA
and this manager did DBA too
but these guys did not
```

and test_file2.txt:

```
This is another file
which checks the Manager
DBA thing
```

I ran this:

```
grep -o "Manager\|DBA" *.txt | sort | uniq -c | awk -F "[: ]+" '{printf %s:%s:%s\n", $3, $4, $2}'
```

To get this output (note it is case sensitive):

```
test_file2.txt:DBA:1
test_file2.txt:Manager:1
test_file.txt:DBA:2
test_file.txt:Manager:3
```

Hope that's what you were after.